# Where is that functor which free monad is supposed to be based on

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, scala-cats, free-monad

I'm trying to comprehend the idea of free monad, and I'm stumped on the first sentence of [cats's docs](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html) stating that

> A free monad is a construction which allows you to build a monad **from
>   any Functor**

My confusion is mainly related to the fact that there is no any functor used\created in the process of "freeing" ADT for `KVStoreA`. There is no implementation of functor for ADT or something like that. However, documentation for `Free[S[_],A]` says that `S` must me a functor:

> A free operational monad for some functor `S`.

Where is that functor that free monad is supposed to be based on?

Comment: Interesting. So having `Yoneda`'s Functor can we construct a `Monad` for any `F[_]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, Free monad can be used in a few different ways. In order to use one of them you assume that you have some functor `S[_]`, it will have some `Functor[S]` defined and you will lift that `S[*]` to `Free[S, *]` by allowing some sort of extension to the original `S`:

```
Free[S, A] = S[A] or A
```

> This is not valid Scala! They way it is actually implemented is using [ADT](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Free.scala#L199). This only serves as an explanation of the idea.

This way if you have `S[A]` and you `map` it with `f: A => B`, you would use `Functor[S]` and receive `S[B]`. But if you `flatMap` it with `f: A => Free[S, B]`... you would still be able to calculate that using `Functor[S]` and receive `S[Free[S, B]]`. That's what this code would be be underneath. Remembering that `Free[S, A] = S[A] or A` you could see that this would turn into `S[S[S[...]]]` and it could go infinitely nested if not for `or A` part of `Free[S, A]` which would let us stop at some point.

Of course we don't calculate it all at once, Free usually uses trampoline to calculate only one thing at a time, so we aren't gonna end with tons of nesting at once.

```
sealed abstract class Free[S[_], A] extends Product with Serializable {
  // ...
}
object Free extends FreeInstances {

  /**
   * Return from the computation with the given value.
   */
  final private[free] case class Pure[S[_], A](a: A) extends Free[S, A]

  /** Suspend the computation with the given suspension. */
  final private[free] case class Suspend[S[_], A](a: S[A]) extends Free[S, A]

  /** Call a subroutine and continue with the given function. */
  final private[free] case class FlatMapped[S[_], B, C](c: Free[S, C], f: C => Free[S, B]) extends Free[S, B]

  ...
}
```

> This trampoline representation implements the same idea as `S[A] or A` but it allows running computations one step at a time. It also shows that `Free[S, *]` is `S[*]` algebra extended by `pure` and `flatMap` operations (that assume nothing about S), which justifies calling Free a [free algebra](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Free_algebra).

Actually, until we decide to run the computations we only have lazily evaluated data structure. One way of running it is to call `free.run` that you [have defined for Free in cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Free.scala#L104) - it will use trampoline to evaluate each of this nestings, one at a time, but then it will use `Comonad[S]` to extract the value - as a result we will get rid of nestings as we go. `Comonad[S]` is also `Functor[S]` which is why we don't have to provide it separately to do all these `map`s.

But that is one way of running things. Another way of running things is just assuming that we are recording the `map`, `flatMap` and `pure` operations using `Free`. For that we don't have to have `Functor[S]` at all. We might decide to `run` things using `Comonad[S]`, but we might also decide something else. What if we translated `S[_]` to some `M[_]`, but that we knew that this `M[_]` had a `Monad[M]`? In this case, we wouldn't have to use `Functor[S]` at all! We would run translation `S ~> M`, then, map or flatMap on it, and the `S` inside of it would be translated using the same `S ~> M` mechanism. This is what [`foldMap` does](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/free/src/main/scala/cats/free/Free.scala#L153) - it requires us to provide a natural transformation `S ~> M` and instance of `Monad[M]` and `Functor[S]` is completely unnecessary. While conceptually we can still consider that `S` as a functor we don't need to rely on any of functors properties, not in the form of `Functor[S]`.

So to finally answer your question - with Free when we are still at the stage of "recording operations" we don't have to assume that `S` is a functor, so we don't need `Functor[S]`. When we want to interpret `Free[S, A]` into something - this is where functor might be actually needed, e.g. if we want to run `Free[S, A]` into `A`. But for some interpretations like e.g. `foldMap` (which is IMHO one of the most popular ones) this is not needed because we treat `S` as a plain data.